# I added Recycler view in fragment, now I am trying to pass image to recycler view, but app is crashing with error msg on logcat

Tags: android-recyclerview, fragment

Error on logcat:

2021-02-18 00:36:44.712 11507-11507/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chitchat, PID: 11507
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.chitchat.RecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:56)
at com.example.chitchat.RecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:16)

//////////////////////code from fragment activity////////////////////

```
package com.example.chitchat;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link homefragrent#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class homefragrent extends Fragment {


    private RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
//    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;



    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public homefragrent() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment homefragrent.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static homefragrent newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        homefragrent fragment = new homefragrent();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefragrent, container, false);


        recyclerView= (view).findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        ArrayList<postmodel> exampleimgs = new ArrayList<>();

        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.oner,"post1"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.twor,"post2"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.threer,"post3"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.fourr,"post4"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.fiver,"post5"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.sixr,"post6"));
        exampleimgs.add(new postmodel(R.drawable.node,"post7"));


//        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(exampleimgs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);


        return view;
    }
}
```

///////////////Recycle arapter//////////////////

```
package com.example.chitchat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.RecycleViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<postmodel> imgsl;



    public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<postmodel> imgsl) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imgsl = imgsl;
    }

    public class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public RecycleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homefrgmentlayout,parent,false);
        RecycleViewHolder recycleViewHolder = new RecycleViewHolder(view);
        return  recycleViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        postmodel currentposition = imgsl.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentposition.getImgs());
        holder.textView.setText(currentposition.getComment());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imgsl.size();
    }



}
```

//////////////////////////////model class//////////////////////

```
package com.example.chitchat;

public class postmodel {

    private int imgs;
    private  String comment;

    public postmodel(int imgs, String comment) {
        this.imgs = imgs;
        this.comment = comment;
    }


    public int getImgs() {
        return imgs;
    }

    public void setImgs(int imgs) {
        this.imgs = imgs;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel here it would be

```
//Pass context from Activity to the adapter
imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources.getDrawables.image)
```

In Activity

```
recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(this,exampleimgs);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
```

In Adapter

```
public RecycleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<postmodel> imgsl) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imgsl = imgsl;
}
```

and then the above line to set image

Comment: its done thank you for support, issue was in binding